# boost::any constructors - const type overload resolution

Tags: c++, boost, boost-any

boost::any has a perfect forward constructor declared as:

```
template<typename ValueType>
any(ValueType&& value
    , typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_same<any&, ValueType> >::type* = 0 // disable if value has type `any&`
    , typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_const<ValueType> >::type* = 0) // disable if value has type `const ValueType&&`
  : content(new holder< typename decay<ValueType>::type >(static_cast<ValueType&&>(value)))
{}
```

The is_const<> SFINAE exclusion forces const types to the regular copy constructor:

```
template<typename ValueType>
any(const ValueType & value)
  : content(new holder<
        BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME remove_cv<BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME decay<const ValueType>::type>::type
    >(value))
{}
```

What is different about how the regular copy constructor treats a const value than what the perfect forward constructor would do if the is_const<> exclusion were removed?

Comment: given the manual `static_cast<ValueType&&>` I would say that the first constructor is specifically only for r-value references.

Comment: FTR "routing" is overload resolution

Answer (score 0):

The first one is specifically for rvalue refs (the `enable_if` ensures it).

The static_cast is synonymous for using `std::move`, so it would move.